# set the MaxReceivedMessageSize in wcf

Tags: wcf

We've recently developed a wcf based service. And started exposing to external clients. But sometimes, they receive the maximum message size exception. I know that they can set in the config file and it'll work. But, it really looks bad on our side. Is there any way I can set the proper size on my side and stop causing this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It needs to be set on the **client** as they are receiving the large message.

Example:

```
<binding
   name="YourNameHere"
   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
</binding>
```

Comment: Thansk for reply. Management is not ready to adopt this solution. Is there any way I can control from the server side. And to be honest, no one in our company is expert in WCF. So, I need help from community.

Comment: haha...whether management is ready or not is irrelevant. The problem (unless I'm misunderstanding) is that you are sending more data back to the client than the client is configured to accept. It's a problem on the client side, not the server side. Even if you make the change on your side, it will have no effect on the client side.

Comment: I think it's also important for you to understand why this is...it's a security feature built into WCF. That property is intended to limit your service's exposure to denial of service (DoS) attacks.

Comment: @BrandonZeider Your comments make sense to me. But, it's hard to convince Mgmt. So, to find middle way, how do I find out the max message size exposed by my service? So that I can tell the clients upfront that, this should be the value they should set in the config.

Comment: So your management thinks the problem is on your end? Here is an article that gives an easy way to determine the value. Please be aware that this value is likely to change based on which operation is invoked, what parameters are passed in, etc. http://craigrandall.net/archives/2009/04/maxreceivedmessagesize/

Comment: So did I answer your question?

Comment: I hope this article will solve the problem in terms of size. I haven't had a chance to go though it yet though. Thanks a lot for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using WCF Behaviors.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx